# Dynamic Component inside ngx-datatable row-detail

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm creating a reusable datatable using ngx-datatable and I would like to have dynamic components rendered inside the row detail. The datatable component receives a component class as an argument from a parent module and I use ComponentFactory to createComponent. I can see that the constructor and the onInit methods are running for the dynamic component but it is not being attached to the DOM.

This is what the datatable html looks like for the row-detail :

```html
 <!-- [Row Detail Template] -->
        <ngx-datatable-row-detail rowHeight="100" #myDetailRow (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
          <ng-template let-row="row" #dynamicPlaceholder let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
          </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-row-detail>
 <!-- [/Row Detail Template] -->
```

And this is what my .ts file looks like :

```js
@ViewChild('myDetailRow', {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) myDetailRow: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild('dynamicPlaceholder', {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) dynamicPlaceholder: ViewContainerRef;

renderDynamicComponent(component) {
        var componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        var hostViewConRef1 = this.myDetailRow;
        var hostViewConRef2 = this.dynamicPlaceholder;
        hostViewConRef1.createComponent(componentFactory);
        hostViewConRef2.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```

Another point is that if my `#dynamicPlaceholder` ng-template is placed outside of ngx-datatable, it works and the dynamic module is rendered and displayed.

Comment: This is to do with content projection. Anything placed inbetween a component tag, is not rendered unless the component has a `<ng-content>` tag to render any nested markup.

Comment: Could you please help me with a quick example to help in my case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't render a component into a Template (`<ng-template>`) at runtime with `createComponent`
because afaik templates get processed by Angular at compile time. So we need a solution that works at compile time.

---

**Solution with drawbacks**

`ng-content` can help us here:

```html
<!-- [Row Detail Template] -->
<ngx-datatable-row-detail rowHeight="100" (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
   <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
   </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-row-detail>
<!-- [/Row Detail Template] -->
```

We can then pass anything we want to the detail view:

```
<my-table>From the ouside but I cant access the current row :(</my-table>
```

**But there is a problem:** We can't use `ng-content` when we want to access the current row in the passed template.

---

**Solution**

But `ngx-datatable` got us covered. We can pass a template to the`ngx-datatable-row-detail` directive:

```html
<ngx-datatable-row-detail [template]="myDetailTemplate "rowHeight="100" (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
</ngx-datatable-row-detail>
```

The template can then be passed into from any component on the outside via a `@Input` variable:

```html
<ng-template #myDetailTemplate let-row="row">
  From the outside with access to the current row: {{row.name}}
</ng-template>
```

Take a look at the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datadable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), where I wrote a `my-table` component as poc.

Comment: Looks row-detail has removed cover of template.

Answer (score 0):

> Define a component that exposes its content as `TemplateRef`

```html
<ng-template #myTemplate let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>

    <div><strong>Address</strong></div>
    <div>{{ row?.address?.city }}, {{ row?.address?.state }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

> Use `ViewChild` to make an accessible property for `TemplateRef`

```js
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("myTemplate",{static:true}) myTempalte : TemplateRef<any>
  ...
}
```

> Define your row detail without template

```html
<ngx-datatable-row-detail rowHeight="100" (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
</ngx-datatable-row-detail>
```

> Define a property to access the directive

```js
@ViewChild(DatatableRowDetailDirective,{static:true}) templ:DatatableRowDetailDirective; 
constructor(  
    private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver, //import cfr
  )
....
toggleExpandRow(row) { 
   const factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory<DynamicComponent>(
      DynamicComponent
    );
  
    const component = factory.create(this.injector,[]);   //create component dynamically
    this.templ._templateInput = component.instance.myTempalte; // set directives template to your components template 
    this.table.rowDetail.toggleExpandRow(row);
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tahofa-ngx-datatable-dynamic-rowdetail-template)

**Edit:**  I fiddled with `ngx-datatable` source sad part of it `ngx-datatable-row-detail` is not a component but  directive and it isn't attached to DOM. So it has no `ViewContainer` ref. This makes injecting elements into it a little bit hard. What you can do is define templates in your component and use `TemplateRef`s and assign them where you render your component.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried adopting your method but i'm getting `el.setAttribute is not a function` error on the componentFactory.create method. Any idea why that may be happening? this.dynamicPlaceholder.elementRef.nativeElement returns a comment, could that be it?